# Why does my Greasemonkey JQuery script that hides the sidebar work on Stack Exchange sites but not Stack Overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I get distracted by the Related Questions and Hot Network Questions in the side bar, so I wrote a Greasemonkey script to hide them. The script works on Stack Exchange sites, but not on Stack Overflow itself.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        minimal-stack-exchange
// @include     http://www.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://www.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @description Hide distracting links from StackExchange pages
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

$("#sidebar").hide();
$("#herobox").hide();
$("#footer").hide();
```

I've cleared my Firefox caches, used Inspect Element to determine that I'm using the right div ID, but without success.

Comment: They could intentionally strip out `www` on a domain redirect, never written/seen a grease monkey script though. That wildcard won't work AFAIK

Comment: Does it work on meta? Because my first thought is that Stack Overflow is found at `http://stackoverflow.com` no `www`.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the problem turned out to be specific about the actual website you put in, and not actually anything really to do with the code or the methodology, so unlikely to help future viewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, a better solution is to use [`@match`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match) instead of `@include`.    `@match` intelligently handles the leading `*.` and offers better performance and security, especially on Chrome.

The following `@match` directives accomplish:

1. Match **all** Stack Exchange sites.  (The question @includes miss some important ones.)
2. Match both `http://` and `https://`, since all Stack Exchange sites support SSL.

```js
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
```

---

Note: For practical scripts, I recommend that you also exclude certain Stack Exchange pages unless you are explicitly coding for them.

See ["Complete list of sites to @include / @match into my script?"](https://stackapps.com/questions/4188/complete-list-of-sites-to-include-match-into-my-script) on *Stack Apps*.

Comment: Thank you for the help; this is a much more informative (and general) answer than mine.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was that `http://stackoverflow.com` isn't captured by the wildcard `http://*.stackoverflow.com/*`, so adding another include line fixed the problem.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        minimal-stack-exchange
// @include     http://www.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://www.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     http://stackexchange.com/*
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @description Hide distracting links from StackExchange pages
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==


$("#sidebar").hide();
$("#herobox").hide();
$("#footer").hide();
```